# Is there somethone wrong with my Object Scope?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scope

This is a program I'm writing (myself as opposed to copying someone else's and thus not learning) as part of the ObjectiveC and Cocoa learning curve. I want to draw simple shapes on a NSView (limiting it to ovals and rectangles for now). The idea is that I record each NSBezierPath to an NSMutableArray so I can also investigate/implement saving/loading, undo/redo. I have a canvas, can draw on it as well as 2 buttons that I use to select the tool. To handle the path I created another object that can hold a NSBezierPath, color values and size value for each object drawn. This is what I want to store in the array. I use mouseDown/Dragged/Up to get coordinates for the drawing path. However, this is where things go wonky. I can instantiate the object that is supposed to hold the path/color/etc. info but, when I try to change an instance variable, the app crashes with no useful message in the debugger. I'll try to keep my code snippets short but tell me if I need to include more. The code has also degenerated a little from me trying so many things to make it work.

Project: Cocoa document based app
I have the following .m/.h files

- `MyDocument:NSDocument` - generated by XCode
- `DrawnObject:NSObject` - deals with the drawn object i.e. path, color, type (oval/rect) and size
- `Canvas:NSView` - well, shows the drawing, deals with the mouse and buttons

Canvas is also responsible for maintaining a `NSMutableArray` of `DrawnObject` objects.

`DrawnObject.h` looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//The drawn object must know what tool it was created with etc as this needs to be used for generating the drawing

@interface DrawnObject : NSObject {
    NSBezierPath * aPath;
    NSNumber * toolType;//0 for oval, 1 for rectangular etc....
    float toolSize;
    struct myCol{
        float rd;
        float grn;
        float blu;
        float alp;
    } toolColor;
}

-(void)setAPath:(NSBezierPath *) path;
-(NSBezierPath *)aPath;
@property (readwrite,assign) NSNumber * toolType;
-(float)toolSize;
-(void)setToolSize:(float) size;
-(struct myCol *)toolColor;
-(void)setCurrentColor:(float)ref:(float)green:(float)blue:(float)alpha;

@end
```

`Canvas.h` looks like this

```
#import 
#import "drawnObject.h"

@interface Canvas : NSView {
    NSMutableArray * myDrawing;
    NSPoint downPoint;
    NSPoint currentPoint;
    NSBezierPath * viewPath;//to show the path as the user drags the mouse
    NSNumber * currentToolType;
    BOOL mouseUpFlag;//trying a diff way to make it work
    BOOL mouseDrag;
}

-(IBAction)useOval:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)useRect:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showTool:(id)sender;
-(NSRect)currentRect;
-(NSBezierPath *)createPath:(NSRect) aRect;
-(void)setCurrentToolType:(NSNumber *) t;
-(NSNumber *)currentToolType;
@end
```

In the `Canvas.m` file there are several functions to deal with the mouse and NSView/XCode also dropped in 
`-(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame` and `-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect` Originally I use `mouseUp` to try to insert the new `DrawnObject` into the array but that caused a crash. So, now I use two `BOOL` flags to see when the mouse was released (clunky but I'm trying....)in `drawRect` to insert into the array. I've included the method below and indicated where it causes the app to fail:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect { //This is called automatically
    // Drawing code here.
    //NSLog(@"Within drawRect tool type is %d", [self currentTool]);
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
    NSRect aRect = [self currentRect];
    viewPath = [self createPath:aRect];
//the createPath method uses the tool type to switch between oval and rect bezier curves

    if(mouseUpFlag==YES && mouseDrag==YES){
        mouseDrag=NO;
        //Create a new drawnObject here 
        DrawnObject * anObject = [[DrawnObject alloc]init];//- WORKS FINE UP TO HERE
        NSLog(@"CREATED NEW drawnObject");
        [anObject setAPath:viewPath]; //- INSTANT APP DEATH!!!!
        NSLog(@"Set a path in drawnObject");
        [anObject setToolType:[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:5]];
        NSLog(@"Set toolType in DrawnObject");
        [anObject setToolType:currentToolType];

        [myDrawing addObject:anObject];
        NSLog(@"Added Object");
    }   

    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0 green:0.9 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5]set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];


    [[NSColor lightGrayColor]set];
    [viewPath stroke]; //This is so the user can see where the drawing is being done

    //Now, draw the paths in the array
    [[NSColor blueColor]set];
    for(DrawnObject * indexedObject in myDrawing){
        [[indexedObject aPath] stroke];//This will do the actual drawing of ALL objects

    }


}
```

I guess this has something to do with object scope or something but I just can not figure it out. As I said, as I've tried things the code has sort of undergone an metamorphosis, sadly not for the better. Like those BOOLS etc.

**HELP! Any clever people out there, point me in the right direction please!**

ADDED THIS ON:

```
-(NSBezierPath *)createPath:(NSRect) aRect
{

    NSBezierPath * tempPath;
    //I need to know what tool

    switch(0){  //temporary - this would use the toolType as a selector
        case 0:
            tempPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:aRect];
            break;
        case 1:
            tempPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:aRect];
            break;
        default:
            tempPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:aRect];
            break;
    }
    return tempPath;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the implementation of setAPath from DrawnObject.m.

Comment: -(void)setAPath:(NSBezierPath *) path
{
 NSLog(@"Recorded Path");
 aPath = path;
}

Comment: I guess I should do the release/retain bit but the point is, it never even gets to the NSLog in the method.

Comment: What is your -init method in DrawnObject.m? Perhaps the initialization is wrong so when it attempts to access the ivars it crashes. Step through in the debugger.

Definitely read over the Memory Management guidelines—your code has some violations, but nothing that should cause a crash right there.

Comment: <code>-(void)init
{
 [super init];
 //set default color = black
 toolColor.rd=1.0;
 toolColor.grn=1.0;
 toolColor.blu=1.0;
 toolColor.alp=1.0;
 
 //set default size
 toolSize=0.8;
 
 //set default toolType
 toolType=0; //oval
 
 NSLog(@"Init %@",self);
}
</code>
You guys rock.

Comment: Ooh, that code snippet did not show well. does it make sense. I don't think there is a problem there as I get the "Init" message in the console. It's only when I try to change any instance variable (inc toolType or toolSize) that it crashes.

Comment: One problem in your DrawnObject's init method could be that you're setting the toolType instance variable to 0 instead of [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0]. That has the effect of setting it to nil. I don't think it's what you intended, but I also don't think it's the cause of your crash.

Comment: Oh, one other major problem with your -init just jumped out at me.

You're not returning self at the end and your declaration is wrong. It should be -(id)init, not (void)

As it is I don't think you're -init method is ever getting called at all.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. You're right, I missed the return self. (embarrassed grin) but it is getting called as I get the "Init" message in the console. I'm stepping through with the debugger and I ger a EXC_BAD_ACCESS as soon as I call [anObject setAPath:viewPath] in drawRect. Not sure why...

Comment: Ashley - you asked about the create path - I answered that below. 
It is essentially a switch that uses the toolType to select a tempPath = [NSBezier bezierPathWithOval/RectangleInRect: aRect]; and then returns tempPath

Comment: If your init wasn't returning self then your anObject variable was never getting set to your initialized object; it wouldn't be referencing intialized memory and that's probably giving you your crash.

Try "po anObject" at the (gdb) prompt to print out the object at the point of your crash

Comment: po result:
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000020
0x93c56688 in objc_msgSend ()

Comment: Your anObject variable is not initialized. Changing your init declaration and returning self should fix this particular crash. I'd definitely encourage reading up on the memory management guidelines though before you do much else as you've got several issues through your code there.

Comment: Ashley - thanks, you are a star. I have to say, coming from a straight C51 for embedded controllers, it's a bit of a steep learning curve. Thanks to people like you it is a lot smoother!! Thanks! Some issues is cause I tried to strip the code down to try and isolate the problem.But mostly NOOB probs

Answer (score 2):

You said your init method was:

```
-(void)init {
[super init];
//set default color = black
toolColor.rd=1.0;
toolColor.grn=1.0;
toolColor.blu=1.0;
toolColor.alp=1.0;
//set default size
toolSize=0.8;
//set default toolType
toolType=0;
//oval
NSLog(@"Init %@",self);
}
```

This is ***definitely*** wrong; read up on how to create an init method in the Obj-C guide or by reading sample code. Here's what it should look like:

```
-(id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    //set default color = black
    toolColor.rd=1.0;
    toolColor.grn=1.0;
    toolColor.blu=1.0;
    toolColor.alp=1.0;
    //set default size
    toolSize=0.8;
    //set default toolType
    toolType=0;
    //oval
    NSLog(@"Init %@",self);
}
return self;
}
```

By not returning anything from -init, you were preventing the object's creation. Good luck! :-)

**Edit:** Ashley beat me to it...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by “crash”?

Does anything appear in the Debugger Console (⇧⌘R)?

Does a stack trace appear in the Debugger window?

If there's a stack trace, where in your code does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

It just hangs. In the debugger I see:

```
  [Session started at 2008-11-28 14:40:34 +1000.]
2008-11-28 14:40:36.157 CH18Challenge_try2[1893:10b] Mouse Down at (80.000000,285.000000)
2008-11-28 14:40:36.333 CH18Challenge_try2[1893:10b] Mouse Up at (166.000000,217.000000)
2008-11-28 14:40:36.348 CH18Challenge_try2[1893:10b] Init 
2008-11-28 14:40:36.349 CH18Challenge_try2[1893:10b] CREATED NEW drawnObject

[Session started at 2008-11-28 14:40:36 +1000.]
Loading program into debugger…
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-962) (Sat Jul 26 08:14:40 UTC 2008)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".Program loaded.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to program: `/Users/johan_kritzinger/Documents/Cocoa/CH18Challenge_try2/build/Debug/CH18Challenge_try2.app/Contents/MacOS/CH18Challenge_try2', process 1893.
(gdb)
```

Then I have to force quit to stop it.

Comment: Sorry, that was the debugging console. In the Debugger I see it indicates that <em>indexedObject is out of scope</em>. And that is what I don't understand. I'm probably just slow on the uptake..
As I mentioned, I'm a noob - where would I look for a stack trace?

Comment: If it crashed before it got to the for-loop then the indexedObject variable doesn't exist yet.

What does the implementation of createPath: look like?

Comment: case 0: tempPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOval:aRect];
break;

//other cases eg for rectabngle
}//close switch
retuen tempPath;
}

Comment: The stack trace is in the upper-left list in the Debugger window.

Your problem is that bezierPathWithOval: doesn't exist. The correct selector is bezierPathWithOvalInRect:.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the implementation of setAPath from DrawnObject.m. Also, for the "stack trace" look on the upper left of the debugger--it should list a stack of functions showing where in your code the crash is. Make sure you're running in Debug mode, not Release.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this is what the stack trace is saying (there are 22 items but only one is black): -[Canvas drawRect:] and if I click on that the right hand pane of debuggers says indexedObject out of scope. Could it be that my implementation of the for loop is wrong in drawRect?

Comment: No, the crash has nothing to do with indexedObject or the loop. "out of scope" just means that you haven't gotten to the for loop yet, so the object is "out of scope".

Answer (score 0):

On the command line you can type print-object and you can 
set a breakpoint in that line and step through it from there. It seems setAPath is somehow broken

Regards
Friedrich

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a crash. A crash is when a signal is raised (like EXC_BAD_ACCESS) or an uncaught exception.

What you have seems to be an infinite loop.

You need to use the pause button in the Debugger and see exactly where. I would guess that you have an infinite loop in your setAPath: method. You need to work out why this function is looping indefinitely.